# Center equation vertically after passing through hyperref

Tags: equations, hyperref, cross-referencing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
   f(x)=x \label{eq:one}
\end{align}

\eqref{eq:one}
\end{document}
```

With this set up (or without the explicit package imports on StackExchange sites with Mathjax enabled), I get a hyperlink to this equation, but when I click it, the equation itself is at the very top of the screen.

I'm curious if there is a simple way to modify the behavior of hyperref so that links cross-referencing equations will lead to them appearing at the center of the page vertically rather than the top.

Comment: don't show only some snippets but a complete example that can be compiled and used for tests.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sorry about that, I'm used to working with snippets on other network sites. I've updated the question so that it compiles.

Comment: No, since it would require runtime calculation of the current zoom level to jump and adjust the view so the show the (hyper)target vertically centred.

Comment: as Werner says, I don't think that pdf has a sensible view setting here.